# How to properly branch for 1.1.8 and for 2.0 at the same time and merging

Tags: git, git-merge, branching-and-merging

I am starting from `master` and want to create a new `branch` for 2.0 of my app.

At the same time I need to work on some bug fixes which will be 1.1.8, so I need to create a hotfix branch.

My question here is, when I merge the 1.1.8 branch into master, it will update that code base. Then when I want to merge 2.0 will there be major issues since the master has been updated? What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 3):

I would update your 2.0 branch with the changes from 1.1.8 when the hotfix is done, so you basically deal with any conflicts then instead of when you try merge 2.0 to master. I've attached some flows which hopefully help, good luck.

with git flow,

[image]

what you described in your question,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I am starting from `master` and want to create a new `branch` for 2.0 of my app.

```
git checkout -b version_2.0
```

> At the same time I need to work on some bug fixes which will be 1.1.8, so I need to create a hotfix branch.

so far no problem here.

> My question here is, when I merge the 1.1.8 branch into master, it will update that code base.
>
> Then when I want to merge 2.0 will there be major issues since the master has been updated?
> **What is the best practice here?**

The best approach is to do a small merges as possible so you will not have many conflicts at the end.

Another way is to merge the hot fix to master and to the new branch as well so yo will have it on both of the servers.

A good workflow for this kind of development is [`git flow`](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

[image]